# Is giving arguments wrapped inside an object to a function a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, arguments

Usually, as my code base grows, the functions recieve more and more arguments and it becomes a little sloppy to maintain, so I usually just default to something like this:

```
f = function(args){return args.v + 1;}

f({"v":2});
```

It looks way more cleaner, but is it OK to do? Why isn't everyone doing this?

Comment: You'd probably want to start looking into JavaScript classes (OOP) in those cases...   The problem with these 'anonymous objects', is the programmer has to remember (now and six months down the road) what properties are required by a given function.  With a function taking explicit arguments (arg1, arg2) you know more easily (especially if you label your arguments correctly) what the function requires for arguments...   But again, for many arguments, I'd probably suggest OOP if it applies.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it looks way more cleaner, but is it OK to do?"

Yes.

"Why isn't everyone doing this?"

Aren't they though? This is standard practice for the most common "many parameter" situation in Javascript: passing options. Since there's no overhead to creating a one-off object in Javascript, it's common practice when you have more than a couple parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Usually if a function is taking too many parameters it is probably doing too much. You should look into refactoring it into smaller functions/objects.

Uncle Bob suggests functions with very few parameters in his book Clean Code and I agree. It makes it difficult to read code when you have many parameters or pass in an an object or array. I can't guess what the function is going to do with all the parameters or what it is expecting as parameters if your passing in an object without reading the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine - as long as you keep a good level of control over the kind of objects you pass around as variables, and validate these values as necessary (thinking of "false" / null / undefined type issues) then yes, this is good practice. Also a lot easier to maintain.